# GPU-accelerated streaming using WebRTC not connecting [ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused]

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, webrtc, gstreamer, nvenc

I am trying to use [NVENC](https://developer.nvidia.com/NVIDIA-VIDEO-CODEC-SDK) to encode and take that output, stream it to another server using WebRTC and then decode it there.

I tried to follow this [GPU-accelerated streaming using WebRTC project](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/gpu-accelerated-streaming-using-webrtc#network_traversal) to get started.

I would like to run this locally without using Kubernetes Engine on [Google Cloud](https://github.com/selkies-project/selkies-vdi#platform-verification) as given here, but Docker is giving me a lot of trouble.

This is the error thrown when running the command python3 main.py in selkies-vdi-cgc-docs\selkies-vdi-cgc-docs\images\gst-webrtc-app\ :

> python3 main.py main.py:187: DeprecationWarning: The 'warn' function
> is deprecated, use 'warning' instead   logging.warn(args)
> WARNING:root:Namespace(app_auto_init='true',
> app_ready_file='/var/run/appconfig/appready',
> coturn_auth_header_name='x-auth-user',
> coturn_web_uri='http://localhost:8081',
> coturn_web_username='DESKTOP-OAR3JEG', debug=False,
> enable_audio='true', enable_clipboard='true', framerate='30',
> json_config='/var/run/appconfig/streaming_args.json',
> metrics_port='8000', server='ws://127.0.0.1:8080',
> uinput_js_socket='', uinput_mouse_socket='') Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File "main.py", line 223, in 
> stun_server, turn_server = fetch_coturn(   File "main.py", line 56, in fetch_coturn
> conn.request("GET", parsed_uri.path, headers=auth_headers)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1255, in request
> self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
> self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
> self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
> self.send(msg)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 950, in send
> self.connect()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 921, in connect
> self.sock = self._create_connection(   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
> raise err   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
> sock.connect(sa) ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

This is for a screen capture project so it all have to be real-time with very low latency as possible. So any help to get me started on this would be just great!

I am not even sure I running the correct python script.

Excuse me if I am missing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your log is not so clear but for screen sharing you can use this project
https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection